# How to back transform the log transformed obtained BLUEs and BLUPs for linear mixed model in R?

Tags: logging, model, transformation, back, mixed

I am working with a data which i transformed using log as mentioned below

dd111$LogProteincontent <- log(dd111$Proteincontent)

After that i have fitted a linear mixed using LogProteincontent data

lm1 <- lmer(LogProteincontent ~ Year + (1|VARIETY_ENG),REML = FALSE,data = dd111)

Now I want to get the results BLUes and BLUPs in original scale.

I do not understand how to extrat it

I have checked available tutorial but did not correctly implemented